# filepath of uploaded file in asp.net mvc 2

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

i am trying to get the filepath for my uploaded file. Is there a way to get it?

```
    <%= Html.BeginForm("Upload","Home",FormMethod.Post,new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }) %>
<%{ %>

<input type="file" id="upload" name="upload" />

<button id="btnUpload">
    upload</button>

<%} %>

  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase selectedFile = Request.Files["upload"];


        //how do i get the full filelocation here?

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At the point where your comment is the file is not saved - its simply a stream of bytes.

You can access the stream of bytes directly using the `InputStream` property, or you can save the file to some path using the `SaveAs` method:

```
selectedFile.SaveAs(someFile);
```

For more details see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If the browser sends the full path of the file, it's in the `FileName` property. However, most browsers only sends the file name nowadays, as the full file path is useless to the server, and only exposes information about the client unnecessarily.